# How to pass generic list value to InOutArgument declared in Workflow Xaml

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a entity class SEBLInBound as mentioned below

```
public class SEBLInbound
    {
        public int MEME_CK
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public String EligibilityBeginDate
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        }

        public String EligibilityEndDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Char VoidIndicator
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Char ReInstate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public char PriorToGoLive
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
```

I have declared a INOutArgument in XAML with type of this Entity class

```
 <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="ErrorMsg" Type="OutArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="InboundProp" Type="InOutArgument(local:SEBLInbound)" />
    <x:Property Name="argument1" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="argument2" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
  </x:Members>
```

now from cs file i want to pass  list value List to this Xaml for manipulation.

Please let me know, how to pass the value to workflow

THanks in advance

Comment: Its so spectacularly trivial that I'm not sure what you're actually asking.

Comment: my requirement is to have a entity object And use workflow activity rule to manipulate the records in the entity obj and return A result. so i for This is created a entity class and fetched values from db to this as list. now i need To pass this to my activity rule in workflow and get result.

Comment: But if you can't figure that out by simply reading the docs, the chances you can accomplish the rest are slim to none.

Answer (score 0):

You pass objects into Workflow arguments using a dictionary object where the Keys are the name of the argument.

```
IDictionary<string, object> inParams = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"InboundProp", _yourDataObject01 },
                {"argument1", _yourDataObject02 },
                {"argument2", _yourDataObject03 },
            };

_workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(new MyWorkFlow(), inParams)

_workflowApplication.Run();
```